# Multiple EditTexts

Tags: java, android, object, android-edittext

I have multiple edittexts in multiple tablerows.
I know I can access them thru findViewById.
Is there a way to find out in onFocusChange which edittext has focus, instead of using findViewById?

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int edit1 = 0, edit2 = 0, result = 0;
if(hasFocus == true) 
{
        
}   
else {
edit1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
result = Integer.parseInt(et3.getText().toString());
edit2 = result - edit1;
et2.setText(Integer.toString(edit2));
et3.setText(Integer.toString(edit2));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
```

Of course, you will need to do something clever after this - even just a try/catch assuming that the focus is an EditText might be enough.

Comment: Why would it be necessary to access the `Window` instance and ask it for the current focus, when you're inside a `View.OnFocusChangeListener.onFocusChange()` method where you have the information already if `hasFocus` is `true`?

Answer (score 1):

When the user switches from one EditText to another, `onFocusChange()` will be called twice; once for the View which lost focus, and a second time for the View which now has it. (Edit: This sounds like there was an order in which these events arrive, but even if that were the case, it's not guaranteed and you must not rely on it.)

So in your `hasFocus == true` branch, you simply inspect `View v`, see whether it's an `instanceof` `EditText` and there you have your View object.

Comment: At this point as pointed out, you could then Johan use the listener that received the focus change alert to update the main Activity hosting the table where the current EditText is.

Comment: @JaySnayder Yes. In the original question I only read the question _is there a way to find out in onFocusChange wich edittext has focus_, though...

Answer (score 0):

Check if the View v parameter equals the instance of your EditText.

```
if(hasFocus && v == et1) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setTag() in each edittext view and set focus listener in each view.If you don't want to find this using findViewById() than you can retrieve view from parent view programmaticly and assign them tag and set click listener.